# PDO:: Fetch & FetchAll

Tags: php, pdo

Porque o código a seguir funciona:

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dados");
 $stmt->execute();
 $codigos = $stmt->fetch();

 echo $codigos['codigo'];
```

E assim eu não consigo utilizar?

```
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dados");
   $stmt->execute();
   $codigos = $stmt->fetchAll();

   echo $codigos['codigo'];
```

Answer (score 9):

Bom amigo a diferença entre o `fetch` e o `fetchAll` está no retorno. No caso do `fetch` é um array simples, enquanto no `fetchAll` é um array multidimensional, também chamado de matriz. Na sua situação está dando certo o `fetch` por que só tem um registro no banco, a partir do momento que tiver mais de um registro no banco, ele irá lançar um `PDOException`, pois está recebendo mais de um objeto do banco enquanto só suporta um, a não ser que use um `LIMIT 0,1` em sua consulta, porém assim só trará um resultado do banco e não acredito que seja isso que está precisando. Para isso você teria de usar o `fetchAll` e para imprimir na tela teria de usar o `foreach`, ficaria assim o código:

```
foreach($codigos as $item)
{
   echo $item["codigo"];
}
```

Comment: oque eu faço para acesar posições dessa matriz que ela me retorna?

Comment: Com o código descrito acima, fazendo um foreach, assim irá conseguir acessar cada laço do array.

Answer (score 4):

`fetch()` retorna apenas uma linha do array, enquanto `fetchAll()` retorna mais de uma, ou seja esse array é indexado por números, é preciso um laço para exibir todas as informações.

Para pegar os índices númericos use a função [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$codigos = $stmt->fetchAll();
$keys = array_keys($codigos);
```

O array retornado por `fetchAll` é nesse formato:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [nome] => a
        [id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [nome] => b
        [id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [nome] => c
        [id] => 3
    )
```

Comment: eu não consigo 'capturar' esses indices de forma que eu consiga armazenar elas em arrays separados pelos indices que utilizar no select, tu tem uma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: @thiago freitas não entendi, vc quer pegar a chave numérica? Pq precisa guardar eles em arrays separados?

Comment: eu preciso usar um select da tabela e fazer a migração desses dados para outras tabelas, e bom não estou conseguindo armazenar para re-utilizar os resultados obtidos, por conta desse retorno em fetchAll

Comment: vc não irá precisar do valor das chaves para migrar os dados de uma tabela para outra. apenas utilizar o foreach iterar o resultado, e criar um  ou mais insert na outra tabela.

Comment: Se vc está fazendo este codigo apenas para migrar de uma tabela para outra considere fazer isso apenas utilizando SQL. Direto no banco.

Answer (score 1):

Porque a estrutuda de dados é diferente da uma olhada na documentação do [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php) e do [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php) que você verá a diferença. Basicamente acostume-se a utilizar o `print_r` ou o `var_dump` para ver a estrutura dos dados que você está trabalhando

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde Rafael Almeida, estava com a dúvida parecida com a sua, a minha dúvida era o contrario da sua, porque eu estava precisando de uma lista/array de objetos, porém o meu código só me retornava um objeto, então dei uma pesquisada em [PDOStatement]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php
 e vi que o método fetch() me retorna o ultimo objeto so select e o fetchAll me retorna o select completo caso exista mais de um registro no banco.