# como pegar um dado Especifico com PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Como pego o ID de uma tabela usando o PDO?
Tenho esse código porem nao estou conseguindo pegar o ID de uma consulta e passar como parâmetro.

No código abaixo a variável `$id_ref["id"]` não esta enviando o ID como parâmetro.

```
if (!empty($cod_busca)) {

  $query = "SELECT id FROM controle_ntes WHERE cod_busca = :cod_unidade";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(":cod_unidade", $cod_busca);
  $stmt->execute();
  $id_ref = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

    header("Location: ../include-carencia.php?id=" . $id_ref["id"] . "");
```

OBS: sou novo em programação e ainda estou me adaptando e essa plataforma.

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61379/pdo-fetch-fetchall

Comment: Se a consulta vai retornar apenas 1 registro e ela possui apenas 1 campo você pode pegar o resultado usando fetchColumn https://www.phptutorial.net/php-pdo/fetchcolumn/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Vai retornar um array de registros, mesmo que tenha apenas um registro correspondente à sua pesquisa

Uma das formas de acessar esse registro vai ser:

$arrayRegistros = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$arrayRegistros[0]->id

Onde 0 significa que é o primeiro indice do array e lembrando que por você passar como parametro para a função fetchAll "PDO::FETCH_ASSOC", os registros serão retornados em forma de OBJETO, por isso a propriedade é acessada utilizando ->